# How to convert log level symbol into constant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I am creating a new logger and want to configure the log level to equal Rails configuration value.

```
@logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
@logger.level = Rails.configuration.log_level
```

I get an error since level expects integer and log_level is a symbol (:info). How can I convert the :info into something Logger understands (Logger::INFO)?

I tried using:

```
@logger.level = "Logger::#{Rails.configuration.log_level.to_s.upcase}".constantize
```

But constantize does not recognize the symbol:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Logger::INFO
```

Comment: I dont get the error any more. Seems your first try works now

Answer (score 4):

Just found it:

```
Logger.const_get(Rails.configuration.log_level.to_s.upcase)
```

Comment: Is that really the tidiest way of doing this? Nobody suggested anything else in past seven years, so I guess it must be